# Login Authentication work on browser (lab) BUT not on ionicview or ios emulator

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am having difficulties testing my application on Ionic View or iOS emulator.

When I run my app from browser (ionic serve --lab) I am able to send the login http post request, get a proper response and login. However, when I test my app from ionic view or ios emulator, my http request does not seem to be even sent as I get a strange response status code of -1 and no response data (null).

just to note my server has been set up to accept the CORS and it allows cross origin requests.

Has anyone had any similar issue? 
Any help or instruction would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: check your internet connection in your mobile device and see weather you have add meta tag for white list plugin is added

Comment: @MohanGopi my internet is all good. I have the Cordova white list plugin installed but not sure about this meta tag you are talking about! where and what do I need to add it?

Comment: in your index.html page you should add this line **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">**

Comment: @MohanGopi still same issue! :/ Ive got the ios emulator (running on my local) and still get the response status code of -1 looking at logs!

Comment: show me the error you are getting on your divice

Comment: @MohanGopi I am only seeing my logs in console. When I try to login, when it fails, in http error section I pass the response to console and can see the status is -1 and data null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112351/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-comerun).